# Android - how properly trigger getExtra()?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, service

I want to `putExtra()` my object into an intent then send it to a resident service and let it process the object further.

I've implemented the parcelable etc. and I've done the `putExtra()` code. Now I ran into a problem:I don't know how to use the `getExtra()` *smart-ly*.

Most of the examples on this site are about activity to activity communication -  that is, the moment you pass your object or parcelable to another activity is the same moment you launch your target activity, which means all you have to do is to put your `getExtra()` in the onCreate method and you will be all set.

But as I mentioned I wanted a resident service, which means that this service will be created and started perhaps long before my sending a parcelable object.

Of course I can implement a runnable with delay timer which check the intent passed to it on a regular interval but that would be too much of a hassle. Moreover I simply refuse to believe that the android API doesn't have a way to detect a `putExtra()` even. I mean it seems quite unlikely.

So what should I do to get my `getExtra()` in my data processing service called every time a `putExtra()` method was called? I mean java is an OOPL, it is event driven, right? There must be something I can exploit?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want your `Activity` to communicate with a `Service`.  This can be solved using a Bound Service.  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html

To get this to work, you need to override `onBind` in the Service, which returns an `IBinder`.  If both your activity and service are running in the same process, this is fairly straightforward.  https://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html#Binder

Then, in your activity, you get a reference to the `IBinder` by calling `bindService`, and then you can make calls directly to the `Service`.

Comment: So there is no simpler, even less fussy way to do this? Do I invariably trigger some event whenever I call putExtra( )?

Comment: An Intent is just a data object.  Nothing happens externally when you call `puExtra`.  If you want to trigger events, you have to write that code yourself.    There are other ways to do this, including LocalBroadcastManager, or a 3rd party EventBus.

Answer (score 0):

What about RxJava? You can provide Observable into your Service and check all changes with data.

Comment: Whoa a whole library? Too much work for me? There got be a better way. I putExtra(), I inevitably trigger some event, but I don't really know its name, or if it exists at all.